# Gradle: "Refresh All" removes linked project in Java build Path

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx, robovm

I am using libgdx to make a ios game with RoboVM. I am using the latest versions of LibGDX, RoboVM and my Eclipse is up to date.

Recently I have been trying to add Google Analytics thanks to the [Robovm bindings](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings).
I have manually imported the analytics project in Eclipse:
 with File -> Import -> Gradle project

Everyting works fine, I can import and use the classes in my ios project.

But then if I right click my ios project -> Gradle -> refresh all, the build is succesful but it removes the analytics project from the java build path. As a result, when I try to compile my ios project from a terminal with a command line, it doesn't compile since it doesn't fine the analytics classes. I am using "./gradlew -Probovm.device.name=myiPhone launchIOSDevice --stacktrace"

I guess there is a setting or property in Gradle or Robovm that I should change, anybody has an idea?

Comment: Did you follow the steps from [How do I use these bindings with LibGDX 1.x](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings#how-do-i-use-these-bindings-with-libgdx-1x) section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself, it might help others... I ended up creating my own jar from the analytics project, and added it as a library in a separate folder. As described here: https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/blob/master/README.md
This way every new Gradle build correctly links it to my ios project.